# Poplib not working correctly?

Tags: python, python-2.5, poplib

I want to get all the messages from my gmail inbox, but I am facing 2 problems.

1. It does not get all the emails, (as per the count in stat function)
2. The order of emails it get is random.

I am unsure if its the problem with poplib or gmail pop server.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is it non-programming? poplib is a python standard library.

Comment: Mohit: we need a bit more info, can you paste some code? It's not clear how you are getting the list (with stat/list/etc.)

Answer (score 2):

What does your code look like? Using poplib, you're able to decide on the order and number of the messages downloaded. The code from the [poplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html#id2) should work:

```
import getpass, poplib

M = poplib.POP3('localhost')
M.user(getpass.getuser())
M.pass_(getpass.getpass())
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print j
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `imaplib` module since GMail also provides access to email via IMAP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to use [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: libgmail will limit the scope to gmail alone, which does not serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of gmail: https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13291

Try to use recent:username@gmail.com as your email address. At least you'll have all your last month mail in correct order.